# Can i use Node.js as a server side language

Tags: node.js

I want to develop a small 'Employee performance' application . I have some knowledge on client and server side programming,I don't have a clear idea about Node js architecture, I have  good knowledge on javascript, sql , so i choose Node js option for web development. I want to know whether I can start my development with Node js? , Also is there server side security in Node js? , Also is Node js having good scope in the Please correct me if im wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [express](https://expressjs.com/) for node. It's a very minimalist web framework that you can get started with. You can also use the [helmet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/helmet) module for some basic security.